# Blur effect duplicates everytime I open a view

Tags: ios, swift, uiblureffect

I have a `UITabBar`, with the sections, "main" and "profile". In profile I use a background image that fills the entire screen, with a blur effect. It works pretty good. When I go back to main and go back again to profile, a new blur effect is added over the first blur effect.

If I place the code corresponding to set the blur effect in `viewDidLoad()` it works fine, the effect is added just one time. But there's a problem, the blur effect doesn't fill the entire screen. I suppose this is caused because in `viewDidLoad` nobody knows the frame of the `imageView`, so it fills a 3/4 parts of the image.

My question is: how can I fix this? supposing it is caused due to the image frame, that is unknown by now. How do I set the frame measures?

If you think it's caused by another thing tell me what can be.

this is the blur code I'm using?

```
self.picBlurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: self.picBlur)
self.picBlurView.frame = self.profileSubView.bounds    
self.profileSubView.addSubview(self.picBlurView)
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Resize the blurView in didlayoutSubviews after auto layout has applied it's changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have `picBlurView` as a property, simply check if it exists. If does not exist, then create it and add it. Otherwise do nothing. Do this in `viewWillAppear`.

```
if (self.picBlurView == nil){
  self.picBlurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: self.picBlur)
  self.picBlurView.frame = self.profileSubView.bounds
  self.profileSubView.addSubview(self.picBlurView)
}
```

You probably want to implement the method `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` so that you can reapply the blur effect when rotation takes place if that matters to you. In here you just replace the one you added originally.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a flag in your class like "`_alreadyBlurred`". You set it at NO in the `viewDidLoad`.

In `viewWillAppear`, you check if the `flag == NO`, if it does, you make the blur effect and set the `flag = YES`.

Then in the next call it wont add another blur effect, and in this method you know the frame .

Code :

in viewWillAppear :

```
if (_myBlurView == nil) {
    ....
    // do blur effect and add
    ....
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. I think that's the solution! but I don't know how to set a flag and I don't know either how to check it out! What I've done to fix this is remove from superview the blur effect everytime the view disappear, it works, but I know this is not how it has to be done.

Comment: You do not need a new property. Just use self.picBlurView. If it has not been created, create and add.

Comment: Yeah but you've suggered an edit on mine so I edited :P